# HTC Desire stops recording

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an application that records background noise for a long time (up to 12 hours, mostly at night).
I'm using MediaRecorder for the recording.
The problem is that on HTC Desire device the recording stops after about 1 hour, or even shorter time (there is no crash).
On another device, LG-P970h, this doesn't happen at all (i.e., no recording problem).
What is the reason for this and what can I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Doing a bit of guesswork here, but you may have to use a wake lock to keep the device alive during recording.

Comment: I don't want to use wake lock in order to reduce energy consumption.

Comment: It may not be possible. I've seen recording apps that have a setting which allows you to turn the wake lock on or off. That may be the way to go if you don't find another way.